# Newly Created Application Pool Does Not Appear in IIS Manager

Tags: c#, iis

I'm trying to create an IIS application pool on my local machine using the below code. It seems like it runs fine, but when I go to look for the application pool in the IIS Manager, I can't seem to find it.

When I try to create an application pool with the same name, I'm given an error stating that the application pool already exists. What is the correct way to add an application pool that is visible in the IIS Manager?

```cs
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

public static void CreateNewAppPool(string newAppPoolName)
{
    try
    {
        using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
           ApplicationPool newAppPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add(newAppPoolName);
           newAppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0";
           newAppPool.ManagedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Integrated;
           newAppPool.AutoStart = true;

           serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error occured - {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

[image: IIS Manager screenshot]

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know-b82f2c974da6 Your changes went to IIS Express likely.

Comment: Can not reproduce your problem. You can check applicationhost.config and remove the added application pool. How to use Microsoft.Web.Administration create new application pool you can refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/scripting/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration#create-a-new-application-pool.

Comment: @LexLi That is exactly what happened, thank you for the insight. I poked around on your blog and found your article about Microsoft.Web.Administration 7.9.0.0 for IIS Express. After changing it to 7.0.0.0, it's now being added and is visible in the IIS Manager as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hint provided by @LexLi, I was able to find out that Microsoft.Web.Administration 7.9.0.0 targets IIS Express. After changing the reference version to 7.0.0.0 in my project settings, I'm now able to run my code and find the newly created application pool in the IIS Manager.

```
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>%windir%\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply removed and re-added the reference 'Microsoft.Web.Administration' to the project. It automatically pointed to the correct version (7.0.0.0).